# Apache 2.4.7 rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have following Apache url rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]
```

[ source: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html#detecting-the-search-engine ]

These urls worked before upgrading to Apache 2.4.7. (I'm not sure which version I had). Now it always load the home page when used `?_escaped_fragment=/` in query string. Anybody knows how to fix to Apache 2.4.7

UPDATE

directory structure

```
/.htaccess
/index.php
/partials/
/snapshots/
/css/
/js/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in Apache 2.4+:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /snapshots/%1? [L,QSD]
```

`QSD` will discard the query string after redirect.

Comment: Sorry, no luck with your answer

Comment: How did you actually verify that it is not working? Also provide your full .htaccess in question, there might be some conflicting rules.